# API made using bottle not working in browser

Tags: python, rest, bottle

I have made an API on a remote server using bottle. When I start hosting, and then try and access the API using browser, the request gets no response. In fact, the request is not reaching the server itself. However, on using the same with wget, I am getting the required response. Here is the code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from twython import Twython
from bottle import route, request, response, run
client = MongoClient()
db = client.PWSocial
tweets = db.tweets
follower_count = db.follower_count
APP_KEY = 'XXXX'
APP_SECRET = 'XXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'XXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XXXX'
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
id_list = [57947109, 183093247, 89443197, 431336956]

@route('/')
def hello():
    dict1 = {'me': 'hello'}
    result = json.dumps(dict1)
    return result

@route('/api/follower')
def disp_follower():
    ac_id = request.query.id
    fc = list(follower_count.find({'id': ac_id}))
    mydict = fc[0]
    del mydict['_id']
    result = json.dumps(mydict)
    return result

@route('/api/retweet')
def rt():
    ac_id = request.query.id
    retweets = db.retweets
    rt = list(retweets.find({'usr_id': ac_id}))
    result = json.dumps(rt)
    return result

@route('/api/favorite')
def fav():
    ac_id = request.query.id
    retweets = db.retweets
    rt = list(retweets.find({'id': ac_id}, sort=[('rt_count',-1)], limit= 100))
    mydict = {}
    for i in rt:
        a = i.get('id')
        status = twitter.show_status(id = a)
        b = status.get('favorite_count')
        mydict[a] = b
    result = json.dumps(mydict)
    return result

@route('/api/max_rt')
def most_rt():
    ac_id = request.query.id
    retweets = db.retweets
    rt = list(retweets.find({'usr_id': ac_id}, {'usr_id':57947109},sort=[('rt_co
    result = json.dumps(rt)
    return result

run(host= '180.179.212.200', debug=True)
```

Can anyone suggest a reason and a solution for this?

Comment: What request do you make?

Comment: @LutzHorn: Am making get requests..

Comment: In *detail*: which route, which headers?

Comment: @LutzHorn, I am a noob in these things, and cannot tell you much. Though I can say this, wget  http://180.179.212.200:8080/ is working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, its actually a simpple firewall issue. A hole has to be created in the firewall for any such API to run.

Comment: Hi Apoorv, could you explain any further how you solved this? Thank you!